# Fan - always on: Battery drain too high in Ubuntu 12.10 x64

Tags: battery

I bought an Asus U36 ultrabook some time ago, because it had 4-6 battery hours (average real values).

Now that I updated to Ubuntu 12.10 x64, My battery lasts less than 3:15 with the type of use I would get 5 hours at least in Windows 7.

First I wondered that the GPU was always "on", rather that using the IGP (low consumption within ivy bridge). However I ran some commands that clearly have shown that I do not even have the GPU working (only the IGP) - which is fine by me.

I also installed bumblebee and jupiter to try to control the power consumption - but the problem is the same - altough I might notice that with jupiter is less bad (also, on demand governor works fine) - but clearly this not normal. I suppose that in a "normal" notebook with 1:30 battery would get 30 minutes or something (which is very bad).

What can I do ?

It's probably related the very strange fact that: it's cold in my domestic environment, and my fan is ALWAYS working very fast. Even when I'm doing nothing, and has power saving governor.

Comment: One of the problems is the fact that the governor is always set on performance. Jupiter corrects that, but still a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify your governor to "quiet" or "Battery Performance"
2. If you don't know how to do that, go into your BIOS settings and look for a Fan setting
3. If it doesn’t have one, download "Speed Fan" and modify the value, so that the fan will only run when the CPU is active beyond a certain percent, Or when your machine reaches a threshold of temperature.
4. Hope this helped